# Editable JComboBox with dynamic entries

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I made my JComboBox editable using:

```
myCombo.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE);
```

I encounter multible problems with the following task:

When writing into the combobox, the new content of the box should be taken and compared with a list and all entries starting with this text should be shown in the popupmenu.

So if i have a list with: "Aban" "Aben" "Aber" "Acen" "Aden"
and enter "Ab" into the box, then the pop-up should display the first 3 entries.

When clicking one of the entries (Either by keyboard selecting and pressing enter/tab or by clicking with a mouse) The ComboBox should get that value and the Popup should hide. I need to find this action as some of the elements have a note at the end (In backets which I require) but only when one of the entries is selected

Here are the most imporant parts of my code:

```
final JTextComponent tcA = (JTextComponent) myCombo.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
tcA.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
  public void methodUsedByinsertUpdateAndremoveUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    String item = ((JTextComponent) myCombo.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).getText();

    //Routine to get the new list in a vector, not pasted for readability

    DefaultComboBoxModel newMyComboModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(myVectorList);
    myCombo.setModel(newMyComboModel);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        myCombo.showPopup();
      }
    });
  }
}
myCombo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  if(myCombo.getModel().getSize() == 1) {

    //Special logic to find out if the selected item has a note

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        myCombo.hidePopup();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

With this, i have:

1. Trouble with the first character (Caret position not working correctly)
2. Popup not automatically shown and hides when entering new character into the field
3. Problems with Swing GUI not being actualised

If you require more information just ask

Comment: Check out the Auto complete combo from [Glazed List](http://www.glazedlists.com/). Jar is [here](https://java.net/projects/glazedlists/downloads/directory/glazedlists-1.9.0). See [simple example](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/07/19/adding-auto-completion-to-swing-comboboxes.html). I think it does exactly what you're trying to do

Comment: here are a few attempt by using MutableCOmboBoxModel, I'm sure that with Caret, better should be look for AutocompleteComboBox

Comment: @PaulSamsotha your “simple example” link is broken, I think it can (also) be found at https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983168

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Glazed List recommended by peeskillet did exactly what I wanted